# Where does the music of reading Quran comes from?

Tags: quran, tajweed, qiraat

From the day I remember I hear the same sound, pitch and melody when a Qari (a reciter) reads Qur'an. Where does it come from? How did it evolve?

If we look at it from the point of evolution, then we have to expect change both in the past and in future, just the way different styles of music emerge and die out.

Another point of view may be the essential attribution of this melody to Qur'an. This of course requires some proof, because melody is not written in Qur'an, the way it's written and persisted in sheet music.

Comment: How can you associate Qur'an with music?

Comment: No there are some kinds of different styles. The issue is that what you hear are mainly reciters from similar "schools" of recitation. Alone in Morocco in the last century there were at least three reciters with different styles, but one may say they are not mainstream with the mainly Egyptian style of tajweed or the style known from Saudi Arabia. The Iraqi school is said to be different. One of the few reciters that sounds a bit more different these days is Abdarrrashid Sufi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about the Qiraat Styles, the way the Qari recite the Qur'an.

Traditionally, there are 10 recognised schools of qira'at, and each one derives its name from a famous reader of Quran recitation. ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qira%27at))

There haven't been any musical lessons with notes and rhythms, but they just emerged following the way Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) taught his companions.

There is no compulsion though that everyone should recite the Qur'an in one standard style.

> Malik Ibn Anas has reported:  Abd Al-Rahman Ibn Abd al-Qari narrated: “ Umar Ibn al-Khattab said before me: I heard Hisham Ibn Hakim Ibn Hizam reading Surat Al-Furqan in a different way from the one I used to read it, and the Prophet himself had read out this surah to me. Consequently, as soon as I heard him, I wanted to get hold of him. However, I gave him respite until he had finished the prayer. Then I got hold of his cloak and dragged him to the Prophet. I said to him: “I have heard this person [Hisham Ibn Hakim Ibn Hizam] reading Surah Al Furqan in a different way from the one you had read it out to me.” The Prophet said: “Leave him alone [O ‘Umar].” Then he said to Hisham: “Read [it].” [Umar said:] “He read it out in the same way as he had done before me.” [At this,] the Prophet said: “It was revealed thus.” Then the Prophet asked me to read it out. So I read it out. [At this], he said: “It was revealed thus; this Quran has been revealed in Seven Ahruf. You can read it in any of them you find easy from among them. ( vol. 1 (Egypt: Dar Ahya al-Turath, n.d.), 201, (no. 473))

One of the possible reason is that Qira'at helps stress on words which require listener's attention and to inculcate appropriate emotions pertaining to the verses being recited.

And of course the main obvious reason is that it helps us memorize Qur'an faster that way.

Further knowledge can be gained by listening to 10 different Qira'at style Of [Mishari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishari_Rashid) over a verse (Ayat Al-Kursi) from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkKO_NEfBXY)

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: So, is it OK if someone recite Quran in a new tone and intonation? In other words, is it possible that in a century from now, we have more than 10 recognized schools of qira'at?

Comment: yes, @SaeedNeamati as I said, Prophet(pbuh) didn't teach pitches and rhythms, we can recite it in any tune or tone we want. But we need to make sure, we don't make grammatical mistakes(mistakes while pausing) and pronounce the words correctly (Arabic letters are difficult to pronounce perfectly). You can check this... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkKO_NEfBXY